# Installing phpmyadmin to be able to manage the mysql database the admin created for me

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dbmigrate

I dont have access to cPanel. I only can access the root of the site I am working on using FTP, with the domain name, user and password. I want to install phpmyadmin on the root so that I can manage the mysql database the admin created for me. I have the db name, user and password. What do I need to do? Do I need to download phpmyadmin, upload install it? Please give me some details and howto.
Will I actually be able to use it for such?

Also, how to migrate all contents of another mysql databse that I have also access to (having its: db name, user and password) to this one, that was created for the site I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

Download phpmyadmin from the following site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/3.5.8.1/phpMyAdmin-3.5.8.1-all-languages.zip/download#!md5!a65d444787645735c75bca49cdb558cb

Upload it in a seperate folder on your webserver via FTP

Go to this folder and login with your database username and password
Correct the warnings and error on the bottom of the screen
(mostly security issues)

done :)

When you have any questions with errors or warnings please post a new question.